# getting access token by an active facebook session

Tags: facebook, session, access-token

Does anybody know how to get an access_token by using the session cokies from my successfully authenticated session on www.facebook.com?

If you are logged in on facebook.com and go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ then you get graph api links that point to your friends lists, likes, music, etc. with valid access token. How do they get these access tokens?

thanks for your solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Fecabook `cookie` contains `signed_request`. Which can be decoded and have `access_token` within. Read documentation for mere details https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

> The Graph API uses OAuth 2.0 for authorization. Please read the [authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) which provides details of Facebook's OAuth 2.0 implementation, how to request permissions from a user and obtain an access token.

Comment: probably i was not precise enough. the cookies "xs" and "c_user" are available (from a successful login on www.facebook.com) and with these cookies i want to get a valid access_token. 

on developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ ... how did they do that? :/

Comment: that means (according to the authentication guide) also the facebook page itself needs a AppID. developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ requests the access_token by using the user session cookies.
but what is the www.facebook.com AppID then?